# How do I create ZFS pool with 4 drives and mirrors

Tags: zfs, mirror

Is it possible to create ZFS pool with 4 drives (sda, sdb, sdc, sdd) where sda and sdb are mirroring each other and sdc with sdd do the same ?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution

```
zpool create pool -m /pool  mirror /dev/sda /dev/sdb mirror /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
```

Comment: this is right - but you shouldn't need the `-m /pool` as that's the default: the pool's initial dataset's mountpoint defaults to the name of the pool